# Java track objects with an ID

Tags: java, encapsulation

I have this class that everytime I call the constructor should increment the id

```
public class Candidato {
    private String nome;
    private String cognome;
    private final int id;                 // id that tracks number of objects
    private static int counter=0;         //counter that increments the id
    private static int counterd=0;
    private static int counters=0;
    private static int counterp=0;
    private double voti;
    private int doc;
    private int stud;
    private int pta;

    public Candidato(String n,String c){
        this.id=counter++;           //everytime i call the constructor increment me
        this.nome=n;
        this.cognome=c;
        System.out.println(counter+"- -");  // here 
    }
          public int getNumero(){
        //System.out.println(id+"--id--");
            return id+1;
          }
}
```

So my doubts arrise here : Suppose I got a class Elections that calls the Candidato constructor, how can i keep track of the Candidato id everytime a new instance of elections gets created ?

Like in this example at testNumeriCandiati() i get some strange numbers as they are not the expected ones, therefore everytime I create an Election class I want to set the Candidato id back to 0

```
    public class TestR2_Candidati extends TestCase {

        public void testCandidato(){
            Elezione sistema = new Elezione();

            Candidato c = sistema.nuovoCandidato("Marco", "Gilli");      
            assertNotNull("metodo nuovoCandidato() non implemenato",c);
            assertEquals("Marco",c.getNome());
            assertEquals("Gilli",c.getCognome());
            assertEquals(1,c.getNumero());
        }

    public void testGetCandidato(){
        Elezione sistema = new Elezione();

        Candidato c = sistema.nuovoCandidato("Marco", "Gilli");

        Candidato cc = sistema.getCandidato(1);

        assertNotNull("metodo getCandidato() non implemenato",cc);

        assertSame("Non viene restituito lo stesso candidato",c,cc);
    }

    public void testNumeriCandiati(){
        Elezione sistema = new Elezione();

        Candidato c1 = sistema.nuovoCandidato("Marco", "Gilli");
        Candidato c2 = sistema.nuovoCandidato("Francesco", "Profumo");
        Candidato c3 = sistema.nuovoCandidato("Rodolfo", "Zich");

        assertEquals("Non corrisponde il numero",1,c1.getNumero());
        assertEquals("Non corrisponde il numero",2,c2.getNumero());
        assertEquals("Non corrisponde il numero",3,c3.getNumero());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your counter is stored as a static variable of `Candidato`, so its value does not depend on creation of instances of `Elezione`. If you want this funcionality you need to manage the counter of `Candidato` into `Elezione`:

```
class Elezione {
    private candidatoCounter = 0;
    ................

    Candidato createCandidato() {
        return new Candidato(candidatoCounter++);
    }
}

class Candidato {
    private int id;
    Candidato(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have the Elections class create the Candidato objects, and make each Elections instance keep track of the number of Candidato objects created.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the Candidate ID to be unique for each Candidate *within a particular Election* then either a) it needs to be globally unique (and not restart from zero for each election).

Or b) if you need to the number to restart from zero for each Election, then you need a different approach:

Since you have the ID as a static field in the Candidate class, it is shared amongst all Candidates, regardless of Election.

How about moving the ID counter to Election and making it an instance, not class, variable?

Answer (score 1):

static counter in Candidato. Use it when you assign a real id.

```
public class Candidato {
     private static int count=0;
     private int id;

     public Candidato () {
        this.id =++count;
     }
}
```

Then when you create a new instance of Candidato in Elezione class the id of the newly created instance of Candidato will get the incremented id (static, hence, it will be shared with all the instances of Candidato)